# C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled: What does it mean, and how do I fix it?

Tags: c++, runtime-error, bubble-sort

I am making a simple program that sorts a deck of cards by using a bubble sort and then displays it. I am getting a weird runtime error. Can someone explain the error to me and give suggestions on how to fix it?

Error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(341): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\exception(359): warning C4577: 'noexcept' used with no exception handling mode specified; termination on exception is not guaranteed. Specify /EHsc
>
> C:\SortedCards.cpp : fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\SortedCards.obj': Permission denied

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class SortedCards
{
private:
    vector<double> v; 
    int nElems; 

    void swap(int one, int two) {
        double temp = v[one];
        v[one] = v[two];
        v[two] = temp; 
    }

public:
    SortedCards(int max) : nElems(0)
    {
        v.resize(max);
    }

    void insert(double value)
    {
        v[nElems] = value; 
        nElems++; 
    }

    void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nElems; i++) {
            if (v[i] == 11) {
                cout << "A "; 
            }
            else if (v[i] == 12) {
                cout << "J ";
            }
            else if (v[i] == 13) {
                cout << "Q";
            }
            else if (v[i] == 14) {
                cout << "K"; 
            }
            else {
                cout << v[i] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl; 
    }

    void bubbleSort()
    {
        int out, in; 
        for (out = nElems - 1; out > 1; out--) {
            for (in = 0; in < out; in++) {
                if (v[in] > v[in + 1]) {
                    swap(in, in + 1); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    int maxSize = 100;
    SortedCards arr(maxSize);

    arr.insert(1);
    arr.insert(2);
    arr.insert(3);
    arr.insert(4);
    arr.insert(5);
    arr.insert(6);
    arr.insert(7);
    arr.insert(8);
    arr.insert(9); 
    arr.insert(10);
    arr.insert(11);
    arr.insert(12);
    arr.insert(13);
    arr.insert(14);
    arr.insert(1);
    arr.insert(2);
    arr.insert(3);
    arr.insert(4);
    arr.insert(5);
    arr.insert(6);
    arr.insert(7);
    arr.insert(8);
    arr.insert(9);
    arr.insert(10);
    arr.insert(11);
    arr.insert(12);
    arr.insert(13);
    arr.insert(14); 

    arr.display();
    arr.bubbleSort();
    arr.display();
    return 0; 
        
}
```

Comment: It says how to fix it right in the error message.

Comment: How to enable unwind semantics?

Answer (score 4):

`/EHsc` thing is not an error; it is just a warning. The error is about file I/O:

```
Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\SortedCards.obj': Permission denied
```

Just rebuild it after making sure that you have write permission on that file.

Comment: How to make sure that I have write permission on file?

Comment: @QasimImtiaz well, just try deleting it.

Answer (score -1):

it's been 6 years, but I will try anyways. What @ihk is trying to say is to give cl.exe (the compiler here in this case) the read-write permissions in order to allow it to output the file in the directory. you might be able to change that in the properties->security tab section. that should probably do it.

[here is an image of what i am referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDcaT.png)